# Wildfly Swarm 2017.12.1 disable Management fraction

Tags: maven, wildfly-swarm

I have upgraded from Wildfly-Swarm 2017.11.0 to 2017.12.1 and when I start my uber jar I see Swarm is starting fractions that I did not specify to my pom file like Management.
How can I remove those fractions?

Here is my startup log:

```
Installed fraction:                  Logging - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:logging:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:                      EJB - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:ejb:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:                 Logstash - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:logstash:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:         JAX-RS with JAXB - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jaxrs-jaxb:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:                      JCA - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jca:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:          JPA EclipseLink - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jpa-eclipselink:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:          Bean Validation - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:bean-validation:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:        CDI Configuration - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:cdi-config:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:       JAX-RS with JSON-P - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jaxrs-jsonp:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:                      CDI - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:cdi:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:             MicroProfile - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:microprofile:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:              Datasources - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:datasources:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:                  Elytron - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:elytron:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:                   JAX-RS - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jaxrs:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:                      JPA - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jpa:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:               Management - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:management:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:             Transactions - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:transactions:2017.12.1
Installed fraction: Eclipse MicroProfile Config - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:microprofile-config:2017.12.1
Installed fraction: MicroProfile JWT RBAC Auth Fraction - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:microprofile-jwt:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:                  Swagger - UNSTABLE        org.wildfly.swarm:swagger:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:                  Hystrix - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:hystrix:2017.12.1
Installed fraction: Eclipse MicroProfile Fault Tolerance - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:microprofile-fault-tolerance:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:      Microprofile-Health - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:microprofile-health:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:                 Undertow - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:undertow:2017.12.1
Installed fraction:     Microprofile-Metrics - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:microprofile-metrics:2017.12.1
```

And dependencies in my pom file:

```
  <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- DB2 dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
        <version>10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- WildFly Swarm Fractions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datasources</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-eclipselink</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- OTHER DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.kumuluz.ee.rest</groupId>
        <artifactId>kumuluzee-rest-core</artifactId>
        <version>${kumuluzee-rest-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>${modelmapper.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but the `microprofile` fraction seems to be the culprit here. The `microprofile` fraction aggregates all fractions that implement the MicroProfile technologies. Previously, WildFly Swarm implemented MicroProfile 1.0, but since 2017.12, it implements MicroProfile 1.2. The boot log shows that, too. One of the new MicroProfile fractions probably depend on `management`; running `mvn dependency:tree` should tell you which one.

Comment: Yes I already did this. Looks like microprofile-health and microprofile-metrics depend on management. Looks like I'm stick with management fraction then :(

Comment: Well if you don't need those MicroProfile technologies (you were on MicroProfile 1.0 previously, which only contains CDI, JAX-RS and JSON-P), you can remove the dependency on the `microprofile` fraction and add dependencies on whatever fractions you need.

Comment: Well I started to use all the goodies from 1.2 like health and metrics and removed my previous "hand made" implementations of those... So i guess no turning back now :D